# Where do I run "php artisan make:migration posts" on Windows?

Tags: php, laravel

I am following this tutorial: http://www.findalltogether.com/tutorial/simple-blog-application-in-laravel-5-part-1-setup-database/ to set up a blog using Laravel.

In the tutorial, it says to make migrations I've to run `php artisan make:migration posts`. Where do I run this? I tried `bash` but received the error: `Could not open input file: artisan`.

I'm on Windows, using XAMPP - could this be a reason?

Comment: in your root folder where your artisan file is located?

Comment: Oh dear. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Laravel has built-in server (which is using php built-in server). You can start it by typing `php artisan serve` and then your app will be available on `http:\\localhost:8000`. You don't need to use `xampp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go in folder where `artisan` is located (usally root of project) and with CMD or CONSOLE write `php artisan make:migration posts`

Comment: its just artisan, not artisan.php

Comment: yea right, I've wrong copy! and read after your comment ;) sorry ;)

Answer (score 1):

First Navigate to your project directory from command prompt if you have installed the laravel in your project so there should be artisan available you may find by typing "dir" once you find artisan there you should run your respective command. Moreover once you reached to your project directory for testing purpose you may write this line
" php artisan " (without quotes) and press enter you will see all the list of commands available in artisan.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would run `php artisan make:migration posts` in your projects folder.

For example:

Let's say your Laravel project is in `C:\\documents\projects\my-project`, you would need to open the folder `my-project` in the terminal.

**Using Visual Studio Code**

If you have Visual Studio Code, you can open up the project folder in VSC and use the terminal in the IDE by clicking `Ctrl`+`Shift`+ Back Tick Key (`). Then, run` php artisan make:migration posts`.

**Using the Command Terminal**

Open the command terminal and go to your projects directory. Run the command:
`cd path/to/folder`.

Then, once in the project folder, run `php artisan make:migration posts`.